# installing php56w-gd error

Tags: linux, php-5.6

I have installed PHP 5.6 in an amazon Instance in AWS.

```
PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: Jun  1 2016 21:46:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I needed to install a module php56w-gd for image processing. However upon doing so when I run php I encounter this warnings.

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/gd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/gmp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/gmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'SimpleXML' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xml' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to uninstall it and reinstall but the same issue continues. The php56w-gd is also not working properly because the gd.so file is nowhere found.

Heres what I did to install the extension

```
 yum install php56w-gd
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-gd-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                      Arch                                                  Version
====================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php56w-gd                                                    x86_64                                                5.6.22-1.w6
Installing for dependencies:
 php56w-common                                                x86_64                                                5.6.22-1.w6

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 1.4 M
Installed size: 9.1 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/2): php56w-common-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64.rpm
(2/2): php56w-gd-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64.rpm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : php56w-common-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
warning: /etc/php.ini created as /etc/php.ini.rpmnew
  Installing : php56w-gd-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
  Verifying  : php56w-gd-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
  Verifying  : php56w-common-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64

Installed:
  php56w-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6

Dependency Installed:
  php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6

Complete!
```

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your php.ini (or extensions.ini) file and comment-out the extensions that are already compiled-in.
To see which extensions are compiled-in to your PHP binary, run:
php -m